# Specify a url in share this plugin

Tags: php, plugins, share, sharethis

I embedded the http://sharethis.com/ plugin in my website.

But on each site I have a lot of items displayed in a list, each item should have its own share this button.

The user should be able to share the item without accessing the detail view of it via its url.

Is there a way to show share this the url that I want to share? Or does it always just take the current url from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of a year ago `"At this time there is no way to change the URL/title being shared once the DOM is fully loaded."` according to the staff on the [ShareThis](http://forums.sharethis.com/topic.php?id=2163) forum.